# Sum of elements of numpy array not same as total

Tags: python, numpy, precision

I'm trying to count number of pairs and save them in two different histograms, one saves the pair in an array where the parent objects are split and the other one just saves the total, that means I have a loop that looks like this:

```
for k in range(N_parents):
    pair_hist[k, bin] +=1
    total_pair_hist[bin] +=1
```

where both pair_hist and total_pair as defined as,

```
pair_hist = np.zeros((N_parents, bins.shape[0]), dtype = np.uint64)
total_pair_hist = np.zeros(bins.shape[0], dtype = np.uint64)
```

I'd expect that summing the elements of pair_hist across all parents (axis=0), I'd get the total histogram. The funny thing is, if I take the sum of pair_hist:

```
onehalo_sum_ind = np.sum(pair_hist, axis = 0)
```

I don't get exactly total_pair_hist, but something slightly different:

```
total_pair_hist = [  287248245   448773033   695820015  1070797576  1634146741  2466680801
  3667159080  5334307986  7524739978 10206208064 13237161068 16466436715
 19231751113 20949333183 21254336387 19497450101 16459529579 13038604111
  9783826702  7006904025  4813946458  3207605915  2097437543  1355158303
   869077173   555036759   353732683   225171870   143179912           0]

pair_hist = [  287267022   448887401   696415932  1073435699  1644677789  2503693266
  3784008845  5665555755  8380564635 12201977310 17382403650 23929909625
 31103373709 36859534246 38146287402 33454446858 25689430007 18142721164
 12224099624  8035266046  5211441720  3353187036  2147027818  1370663213
   873519714   556182465   353995293   225224668   143189173           0]
```

Any idea of what's going on? Thank you in advance :)

Comment: It's hard to deduce from the code snippets what you are actually doing, especially because the variable names seem inconsistent and some important part is likely missing. Can you create a complete example? ([link to guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))

Comment: can you please include example list/code? Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: I thought it'd be more confusing to show the full code, but it can be found here https://github.com/florpi/pyRSD/blob/master/pairwisevels/indpairwise.py if it helps

Comment: Linking to the full code, certainly without the actual data, doesn't help too much either. Please try to create a [mcve] with an included minimal dataset that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @florpi You are right that the full code is often more confusing than helpful. We need you to find the shortest piece of code (and data; ideally as part of the code) that can consistently reproduce your problem. This requires (probably a lot of) work from your side. But on the bright side, while doing this there is a good chance you spot the issue yourself :)

Comment: That is true, I actually found that the problem was related to numba and using the parallel = True flag, otherwise it works without problems. I'll simplify the code and updated when I get some time, in case someone has the same problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late reply, but I didn't have time to work on it before. The problem was caused by numba. I was using it with the parallel=True flag to parallelise one of the loops and that caused the error.